# Simple Calculator in C# Forms with Running Total

Tags: c#, calculator, cumulative-sum

I am studying online for a generalized degree and we are tasked with developing a simple calculator using .Forms

I was able to create the GUI quite simply, but am struggling with the development in coding a variable that tracks the running total, and allows the user to execute more than one operation.

Currently, my code allows for two inputs and 1 operation. Once totaled, if the user selects another number to operate, the code simply drops the first input and relpaces it with the second original input, then takes the third input and replaces the second input for the new calculation.

for example, if I wanted to add 3 + 6, my calculator would give me 9, but if I then press + 4, instead of getting 13 (3+6+4, or better yet, 9+4) I get 10 (6+4)

I'm hoping someone can point me in the correct direction to create a variable for a running total that tracks the total after an operation is executed and then allows the user to continue performing operations without having to clear the results of only two inputs.

Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IT232M2_McCarver_Par1
{
    public partial class Calculator : Form
    {
        string input = string.Empty;
        string operand1 = string.Empty;
        string operand2 = string.Empty;
        char operation;
        double result = 0.0;

        public Calculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.lblDisplay.Text = "";
            input += 6;
            this.lblDisplay.Text += input;
        }

        private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.lblDisplay.Text = "";
            input += 1;
            this.lblDisplay.Text += input; 
        }

        private void cmdZero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.lblDisplay.Text = "";
            input += 0;
            this.lblDisplay.Text += input;
        }

        private void cmdTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.lblDisplay.Text = "";
            input += 2;
            this.lblDisplay.Text += input;
        }

        private void cmdThree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.lblDisplay.Text = "";
            input += 3;
            this.lblDisplay.Text += input;
        }

        private void cmdFour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.lblDisplay.Text = "";
            input += 4;
            this.lblDisplay.Text += input;
        }

        private void cmdFive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.lblDisplay.Text = "";
            input += 5;
            this.lblDisplay.Text += input;
        }

        private void cmdSeven_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.lblDisplay.Text = "";
            input += 7;
            this.lblDisplay.Text += input;
        }

        private void cmdEight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.lblDisplay.Text = "";
            input += 8;
            this.lblDisplay.Text += input;
        }

        private void cmdNine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.lblDisplay.Text = "";
            input += 9;
            this.lblDisplay.Text += input;
        }
        private void cmdClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.lblDisplay.Text = "";
            this.input = string.Empty;
            this.operand1 = string.Empty;
            this.operand2 = string.Empty;

        }

        private void cmdAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            operand1 = input;
            operation = '+';
            input = string.Empty;
        }

        private void cmdSubtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            operand1 = input;
            operation = '-';
            input = string.Empty;
        }

        private void cmdMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            operand1 = input;
            operation = '*';
            input = string.Empty;
        }

        private void cmdDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            operand1 = input;
            operation = '/';
            input = string.Empty;
        }

        private void cmdEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string runningTotal = result.ToString();

            operand2 = input;
            double num1, num2;
            double.TryParse(operand1, out num1);
            double.TryParse(operand2, out num2);

            if (operation == '+')
            {
                result = num1 + num2;
                lblDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            else if (operation == '-')
            {
                result = num1 - num2;
                lblDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            else if (operation == '*')
            {
                result = num1 * num2;
                lblDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            else if (operation == '/')
            {
                if (num2 != 0)
                {
                    result = num1 / num2;
                    lblDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                   lblDisplay.Text = "Cant /Zero";
                }

            }
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: The `[visual-studio]` tag should only be used for questions about the Visual Studio application.

Comment: There are a lot of things you should look into if you're going to be programming, like the line "input += 0;" and what that means.
But to answer your question, the easiest way in your current code, is that you set operand1 = result in the cmdEqual_Click handler, after you've ran your operation.

Answer (score 0):

As this is an assignment I would expect your code to contain a lot more comments, detailing your algorithm

I think you need to think about how a real calculator works. I assume you're making a simple one where any operation can trigger a calculate if both operands are set - after the calculation if you put the result in operand1 and unset operand2:

Imagine the user presses `1+2+4=`

- Set operand1 to 1
- Set operation to +
- Set operand2 to 2
- Both operands are set so calculate, setting operand1 to 4 and unsetting operand2 and operator
- Set operation to +
- Calculate because = is pressed but don't unset operand2 (because the user can hammer = and add 4 each time)

Consider having a Calculate method that takes a Boolean indicating if it should unset operand2/operator or not. Calculate should always transfer the result of the op into operand1. Whether the operator is set or not should be used to determine if it's operand1 or operand2 that the user is typing. Personally I would do away with input and concatenate operand1 and 2 directly. I'd make the decision as to which to extend in the click handler. I'd have a dedicated variable for when equals had been recently pressed that will unset everything if the user presses a number button after pressing equals, or keeps operand1 and sets a new operation and insets operand2 if it's an operation that the user presses after equals

There are other things we could clean up in your code. This fragment had me puzzled for a while:

```
    private void cmdEight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.lblDisplay.Text = "";
        input += 8;
        this.lblDisplay.Text += input;
    }
```

This would be more logical:

```
    private void cmdEight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        input += 8;
        lblDisplay.Text = input: 
    }
```

But really, if your button just has 8 as its text you can do this:

```
    private void cmdAny_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        input += (sender as Button).Text;
        lblDisplay.Text = input: 
    }
```

And every button uses this same handler

---

If you're making a calculator that understands multiply and divide are done before add and subtract you're going to have to store all the operands and operators in a list and then go through the list doing certain operations first upon pressing equals